# pyarrow not able to handle nulls for required fields when writing to parquet files

Tags: python, pyarrow

I am trying to create a pyarrow table and then write that into parquet files.

```py
def test_pyarow():
    import pyarrow as pa
    import pyarrow.parquet
    import pandas as pd

    fields = [pa.field('id', pa.string(), nullable=False),
              pa.field('name', pa.string(), nullable=False)]
    array = [pa.array(['10', '11', '12', '13']),
             pa.array(['AAA', None, 'BBB', 'CCC'])]
    table = pa.Table.from_arrays(array, schema=pa.schema(fields))
    pyarrow.parquet.write_table(table, 'test_arrow.parquet', compression='SNAPPY', use_compliant_nested_type=True)
    df = pd.read_parquet("/Users/fki/Documents/git/Demo/bq_api/test_arrow.parquet", engine='pyarrow')
    print("\n\n\n")
    print(df)
```

**when nullable is True:**

```
   id  name
0  10   AAA
1  11  None
2  12   BBB
3  13   CCC
```

**when nullable is False:**

```
   id name
0  10  AAA
1  11  BBB
2  12  CCC
3  13  AAA
```

Comment: Does `pd.read_parquet(..., dtype_backend = "pyarrow")` solve it?

Comment: getting error `TypeError: read_table() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dtype_backend'`

Comment: Are you using pandas v1?

Comment: It looks like a but to me (though one might argue that by putting nulls in a non nullable array you are asking for trouble). The bug is in arrow, you can see that `pq.read_table("test_arrow.parquet")['name'].to_pylist()` is wrong. Could create an issue on their github?

Comment: I doubt the issue with read api. As I created table in BQ using this parqet file and i same same data. not sure if BQ is using same api behind the scene. :)